# Angle at intersection by diagonals of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, contest-math, problem-solving, quadrilateral

> Suppose ABCD is a quadrilateral such that$ \angle BAC=50, \angle CAD=60,  \angle CBD=30$ and $\angle BDC = 25$. If $E$ is the point of intersection of $AC$ and $BD$ ,then the value of $ \angle AEB $ is __
>
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

Here is a picture I've drawn of the set up,

[image]

I find that in $\triangle BCD$, we can find $ \angle BCD=125$.

I am not sure how to proceed after that. The most theorems relating angles of a quadrilateral are for cyclic quadrilaterals and this quadrilateral here is not cyclic so I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If it's a multiple choice as in the source: note that angles at $A$ are double of angles at $B$ or $D$:

$$\begin{align*}
\angle BAC &= 2 \angle BDC\\
\angle CAD &= 2\angle CBD
\end{align*}$$

Then $A$ could be the centre of the circumcircle of $\triangle BCD$. Then $AB = AC = AD$, and consider the isosceles triangles.

Comment: Could you show an example solution of the trick you displayed? (I mean in another quesiton) @Troposphere

Comment: Ah, I've heard of it but I'm not much familiar of the circumcentre, I'll look it up again. Thanks @peterwhy

Comment: I've deleted my overcomplicated suggestion -- @peterwhy's observation is the way to go and leads to a definite solution. Note that another way to say "A is the center of the circumcircle" is "B, C, D all lie on a circle whose center is  A". Do you know the [theorem of the inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar, it was only identifying the circumcircle which is difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angles at $A$ are double of angles at $B$ or $D$:

$$\begin{align*}
\angle BAC &= 2 \angle BDC\\
\angle CAD &= 2\angle CBD
\end{align*}$$

This suggests that $A$ could be the centre of the circumcircle of $\triangle BCD$.

(The proof that $A$ is the circumcentre follows below, which involves some construction and may be less important for the multiple-choice question)

Then $AB = AD$ as radii, $\angle ADB = 35^\circ$ as a base angle. Consider the external angle of $\triangle AED$,

$$\angle AEB = \angle CAD + \angle ADB = 95^\circ$$

---

Extend $CA$ to point $C'_1$ where $AC'_1 = AB$. The external angle of the apex of isosceles $\triangle BAC'_1$ is $\angle BAC = 50^\circ$, so

$$\angle BC'_1C = \frac{\angle BAC}{2} = 25^\circ= \angle BDC$$

Similarly, extend $CA$ to point $C'_2$ where $AC'_2 = AD$. The external angle of the apex of isosceles $\triangle C'_2AD$ is $\angle CAD = 60^\circ$, so

$$\angle CC'_2D = \frac{\angle CAD}{2} = 30^\circ= \angle CBD$$

So both $BCDC'_1$ and $BCDC'_2$ are cyclic quadrilaterals, and both their circumcircles pass through the vertices of $\triangle BCD$, so they are all on the same circle.

$CAC'_1$ and $CAC'_2$ are on the same line, hence they are the same chord and points $C'_1 = C'_2$. So

$$AB = AC'_1 = AC'_2 = AD$$

This shows that $A$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle BDC'_1$, so is also the circumcentre of the cyclic quadrilateral $BCDC'_1$, so is also the circumcentre of $\triangle BCD$.

Comment: In a hurry, we can also skip past the middle part: _If_ we draw three rays forming given angles at A, and then construct B, C, D by intersecting the rays with a circle, _then_ the two other given angles will automatically come out right. So angle AEB from that particular configuration is a _possible_ solution, and since it's a multiple-choice test question, we can assume as a meta-given that the solution is unique. :-)

Comment: @Troposphere Yea I think for multiple choice, the middle part is not necessary, and if it's not multiple choice, I don't find the middle part clean enough. But so far for ~1 hour I can't think of a proof of how $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles or how $A$ is the circumcentre.

Comment: It looks convincing to me now -- except how do we know A and O are on the same _side_ of BC? We might need to explicitly assume that the quadrilateral is _convex_ such that we can trust what the diagram tells us about that...

Comment: @Troposphere that's a good point, for example if the quadrilateral is concave at $C$ and segment $BD$ is outside the quadrilateral. For that, I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: The concave-at-C configuration can be constructed using the procedure in Narasimham's answer. It leads to an $\angle BEA$ that is strictly between 85° and 95°. However, arguably it can be rejected by the fact that the problem said $\angle CBD, \angle BCD$ rather than $\angle DBC, \angle DCB$.

Comment: "So both BCDC′1 and BCDC′2 are cyclic quadrilaterals, and both their circumcircles pass through the vertices of △BCD, so they are all on the same circle." what result did you use to state this?

Comment: @Buraian Because the circumcircle of $\triangle BCD$ is unique.

Answer (score 1):

A *construction procedure* for the quadrilateral could be considered. You know to construct triangle BDC.

Next do you know how to construct a circular arc on a given line with given subtended angle?

If yes, then construct circular arcs  on CB,CD containing angles 50 and 60 degrees. The intersection point of these circles is A. All angles can be found at intersection, chasing one by one.